# How do you "restart" receiving Firebase Alerts on short code 44398

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I often use Firebase phone auth in my applications.  I have one user who religiously sends "STOP" to all text messages.  Big oops. Now she can not login to any application using the system...

Short code phone # = 44398

If the user types *"STOP"* to that short code, the system responds with:

> Firebase: You are opted out and will receive no further messages.  For
> HELP, reply HELP.  Msg & Data rates may apply

Type *"HELP"*, the response is:

> Firebase: For more info: https://firebase.google.com/support/ -
> Msg&Data rates may apply.

My question.  How do you "RESTART" the service? The Firebase support page offers no help here.

I've tried "GO", "RESTART", "UNSTOP".  All of those fail.

Here's a [posting on how Twilio addresses the topic.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-)  Twilio uses START, YES and UNSTOP to restart a service (on long code source).  Each of those fail here.

Twilio also provides [a link to standards for short code expressions.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223182208-Industry-standards-for-U-S-short-code-HELP-and-STOP-keyword-responses), but I'm not seeing anything on restarting a service.

Here is a screen shot (of my phone):

[image: firebase stop message]